# Celery connection refused with RabbitMQ running in Docker container

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, celery

I am trying to test an API that sends long-running jobs to a queue processed by Celery workers.. I am using RabbitMQ running in a Docker container as the message queue. However, when sending a message to the queue I get the following error: `Error: [Errno 111] Connection refused`

Steps to reproduce:

- Start RabbitMQ container: `docker run -d -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq`
- Start Celery server: `celery -A celery worker --loglevel=INFO`
- Build docker image: `docker build -t fastapi .`
- Run container `docker run -it -p 8000:8000 fastapi`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /

COPY . .

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r ./requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["uvicorn", "app:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

requirements.txt:

```
anyio==3.6.1
asgiref==3.5.2
celery==5.2.7
click==8.1.3
colorama==0.4.4
fastapi==0.78.0
h11==0.13.0
httptools==0.4.0
idna==3.3
pydantic==1.9.1
python-dotenv==0.20.0
PyYAML==6.0
sniffio==1.2.0
starlette==0.19.1
typing_extensions==4.2.0
uvicorn==0.17.6
watchgod==0.8.2
websockets==10.3
```

app.py:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import tasks

@app.get("/{num}")
async def root(num):
  tasks.update_db.delay(num)
  return {"success": True}
```

tasks.py:

```
from celery import Celery
import time

celery = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://')

@celery.task(name='update_db')
def update_db(num: int) -> None:
  time.sleep(30)
  return
```

Comment: this ``` celery = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://') ``` is exactly how u use?

Comment: @ElvinJafarov thanks for the reply. Yes that's how I'm using it, since in the documentation it says you can specify only the transport and let the rest use default options https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#conf-broker-settings

Comment: USE app = Celery('tasksr', broker='amqp://user:pass@127.0.0.1:port//')  and lets see will it give same error or not

Comment: @ElvinJafarov I should use it just as you wrote it? Or change port with 5672?

Comment: Ofcourse, you should use your port, username, and passowrd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't connect to rabbitmq on `localhost`; it's not running in the same container as your Python app. Since you've exposed rabbit on your host, you can connect to it using the address of your host. One way of doing that is starting the app container like this:

```
docker run -it -p 8000:8000 --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway fastapi
```

And then modify your code like this:

```
celery = Celery('tasks',  broker='amqp://host.docker.internal')
```

With that code in place, let's re-run your example:

```
$ docker run -d -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq
$ docker run -d -p 8000:8000 --add-host host.docker.internal:host-gateway fastapi
$ curl http://localhost:8000/1
{"success":true}
```

---

There's no reason to publish the rabbitmq ports on your host if you only need to access it from within a container. When building an application with multiple containers, using something like docker-compose can make your life easier.

If you used the following `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq

  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

And modified your code to connect to `rabbitmq`:

```
celery = Celery('tasks',  broker='amqp://rabbitmq')
```

You could then run `docker-compose up` to bring up both containers. Your app would be exposed on host port `8000`, but rabbitmq would only be available to your app container.

Incidentally, rather than hardcoding the broker uri in your code, you might want to get that from an environment variable instead:

```
celery = Celery('tasks',  broker=os.getenv('APP_BROKER_URI'))
```

That allows you to use different connection strings without needing to rebuild your image every time. We'd need to modify the `docker-compose.yaml` to include the appropriate variable:

```
version: "3"

services:
  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq

  app:
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      APP_BROKER_URI: "amqp://rabbitmq"
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I found this issue from the Celery git where someone else had the same problem: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3015. They suggested changing the IP of the broker URL to use the IP of the machine. Do you think that has the same effect as your solution? Also in the future I will be deploying with kubernetes, so at that point I should set the URL to be the IP of the RabbitMQ service?

Comment: "Do you think that has the same effect as your solution?" Yes, but it's less portable (because it requires you to know an interface address for the host, while using the `host-gateway` alias means you could run this anywhere).

Comment: Incidentally, getting the connection URI from the environment, as I've suggested, is going to be even more useful when deploying to kubernetes (because if you're running your code locally for testing and also in kubernetes, you may need a different connection string in each environment).

Answer (score -1):

Update **tasks.py**

```
import time

celery = Celery('tasks',  broker='amqp://user:pass@host:port//')

@celery.task(name='update_db')
def update_db(num: int) -> None:
  time.sleep(30)
  return
```

Comment: In the logs for the celery worker, I noticed this message `Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//`. So I set my broker url to `amqp://guest:guest@127.0.0.1:5672//`. However, I am still getting connection refused

Comment: I found that someone had a similar issue in the past: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3015. Do you think this person is referring to changing the broker url here?

Comment: You can't connect to rabbitmq on `localhost` because **it's not running in the same container as the application**.